# jQuery - why it's not working?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is the code of index.php that displays a form with a 'Connect Me' button. I suppose that when user will press that button, it will change to 'Connecting...' and will send the POST data to startTransaction.php script (that is in the same directory) and will show a message after the POST  data is sent, or else will display an error message if any error occurs. But when I press "Connect Me" it just reloads the page. Contents of index.php are:

```
< !doctypehtml > < htmllang = "en" > < head > < metacharset = "UTF-8" / > < title > Freecalls, nosignuprequired! < / title > < linkrel = "stylesheet"href = "css/style.css" />
< scriptsrc = "js/jquery.min.js" > </script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.shake.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#call').click(function()
{
var caller=$("#caller").val();
var receiver=$("#receiver").val();
var dataString = 'caller='+caller+'&receiver='+receiver;
if($.trim(caller).length>0 && $.trim(receiver).length>0)
{


$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "startTransaction.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function(){ $("#call").val('Connecting...');},
        success: function(data){
        if(data)
        {
         $('#box').shake();
 $("#call").val('Connect')
 $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>All set! </span> We'll call you in 5 minutes to connect you. ");

        }
          else
        {
         $('#box').shake();
 $("#call").val('Connect')
 $("#error").html("<span style='color:#cc0000'>Error:</span> An error occured.");
        }
        }
        });

}
return false;
});


});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
<h1>Start making free calls now!</h1>

<div id="box">
<form action="" method="post">
<label>What's your number?</label> 
<input type="text" name="caller" class="input" autocomplete="off" id="caller"/>
<label>And your friend's? </label>
<input type="text" name="receiver" class="input" autocomplete="off" id="receiver" />
<br/>
<input type="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Connect Me!" id="connect"/> 
<span class='msg'></span> 

<div id="error">

</div>
// html closing tags here
```

Please tell me where I am wrong :)

Comment: $('#call').click(function() -- but dont see an element with id call?

Comment: Check your syntax — the first line of your code contains too much white space, and jQuery is not even loaded because of this problematic line: `< scriptsrc = "js/jquery.min.js" > </script>`

Comment: Submitting a form will always reload page, instead of submitting form you need to just execute javascript on click.

Comment: Please next time, use a more descriptive title regarding your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The id of the button is `connect` and not `call`.

```
$('#connect').click(function(){
   //Click on the button
});
```

Answer (score 2):

your script tag to include jquery seems incorrect

```
< scriptsrc = "js/jquery.min.js" > </script>
```

should be (missing space between script and src)

```
<script src = "js/jquery.min.js" > </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
// this is the id of the form
$("#idForm").submit(function() {

    var url = "path/to/your/script.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
               //Or your own code to execute when response is successful
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960586/1275832